# Get C/C++/Latex code from Jaxpr or Jax XLA Computation Object

Tags: glsl, perlin-noise, jax, tensorflow-xla, computation-graph

I am making a procedurally generated terrain for which I used the Classic Perlin Noise give [here](https://gist.github.com/patriciogonzalezvivo/670c22f3966e662d2f83). Now to calculate the normal to the terrain I need the differential of this function, so I rewrote the function in python and used jax.grad to differentiated it. I then created a computation graph as shown [here](http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/python/jax/2022/02/22/jax-outputgraph-rev.html) but it was too complicated to turn into code manually.

The closest solution I have found is the [jax2tex](https://git.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/0moin/google-research/-/tree/master/jax2tex) library but its depricated and doesn't work anymore.

Since I need it for a compute shader, I can't run it using an XLA runtime in C++, I need to write glsl code from it.

My Question is : Is there something like Jax2Tex that I can use that can help me understand the XLA code in an easy to understand way so I can write glsl code from it.

Comment: What is the question? Are you looking for someone to write the code for you? Are you looking for a GLSL tutorial?

Comment: I am wondering is something like Jax2Tex exists that I can use to take my XLA code and be able to write glsl from it.